# Update a list in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have repository class which contains a list with people who filled in a form on my website if they will attend on my party or not.
I read values with the GetAllRespones and I add values to the list with AddResponse (via an interface)

Now I want to check if someone already filled in my form and if so I want to check if the value of WillAttend is changed and update it.

I can see what I did below here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PartyInvites.Abstract;

namespace PartyInvites.Models
{
public class GuestResponseRepository : IRepository

{
    private static List<GuestResponse> responses = new List<GuestResponse>();

    IEnumerable<GuestResponse> IRepository.GetAllResponses()
    {
        return responses;
    }

    bool IRepository.AddResponse(GuestResponse response)
    {
       bool exists = responses.Any(x => x.Email == response.Email);
        bool existsWillAttend = responses.Any(x => x.WillAttend == response.WillAttend);

        if (exists == true)
        {
            if (existsWillAttend == true)
            {
                return false;
            }

           var attend =  responses.Any(x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend == response.WillAttend);
           attend.WillAttend = response.WillAttend;
           return true;

        }

        responses.Add(response);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

the problem is, i get a error message at "attend.WillAttend"

> the error is: bool does not contain definition for WillAttend and has
>   no extension method 'WillAttend' accepting a first argument of type
>   bool could be found

Could anyone help me out fix my code? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
var attend = 
        responses.Any(x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend == response.WillAttend);
```

`Any<>()` returns `bool`. `bool` doen't have property `WillAttend`. If you want to get first response with `x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend == response.WillAttend` use `First()` (or `FirstOrDefault()` but in your case you always will have at least one element, so simply use `First()`):

```
var attend = responses.First(x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend);
attend.WillAttend = response.WillAttend;
```

If you want many responses with specified condition use `Where()`:

```
var attend = responses.Where(x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend);

if (attend.Any())
{
    //do something
}
```

Also, you can make your method simpler:

```
bool IRepository.AddResponse(GuestResponse response)
{
    if (responses.Any(x => x.Email == response.Email)) //here
    {
        if (responses.Any(x => x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend)) //here
        {
            return false;
        }

        var attend = responses.First(x => x.Email == response.Email && x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend);
        attend.WillAttend = response.WillAttend;          
        return true;
    }

    responses.Add(response);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! Implemented the code you suggested, but for some reason var attend keeps being null. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @valheru, have you got `NullReferenceException` or seen value using debugger?

Comment: Fixed it with x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend as suggested by Tamás Szabó and it works fine now. Thank you very much with your help!

Answer (score 2):

`responses.Any(...)` returns a bool value (whether `responses` contains a value you specified). You will have to actually get that value with

```
responses.First(<lambda expression you specified>)
```

for example and get `WillAttend` on that object.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick! To bad an other problem occurred after it

Comment: What was it? Maybe I can help.

Comment: var attend keeps being 'null'

Comment: That must be because there is no object that meets the criteria you specified with the lambda expression. I think you should write x.WillAttend != response.WillAttend since you are looking for a change in attendance.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem! So stupid I didn't think about it myself :)